# CSS positioning

Tags: css

The blocks are not alongside, they are one under the other. i want either A1-A2-A3 to be alongside or A1-A4, A2-A5,A3-A6 to alongside. i will be appreciateed if you can help me. this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>SGKM</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin:0 auto;
        }
        body {
            font:13px/22px Arial;
            color:#444;
        }
        .container {
            width:100px;
        }
        .container2 {
            width:200px;
        }
        a {
            color:#000;
        }
        .stage {
            height:150px;
            width:200px;
            border:1px solid #f0f0f0;
            background:#fafafa;
            margin:60px auto;
        }
        .docIcon {
        background: #eee;
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ddd 0, #eee 15%, #fff 40%, #fff 70%, #eee 100%);
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ddd 0, #eee 15%, #fff 40%, #fff 70%, #eee 100%);
            background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ddd 0, #eee 15%, #fff 40%, #fff 70%, #eee 100%);
            background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ddd 0, #eee 15%, #fff 40%, #fff 70%, #eee 100%);
            background: linear-gradient(top, #ddd 0, #eee 15%, #fff 40%, #fff 70%, #eee 100%);
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            display: block;
            width: 40px;
            height: 56px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="stage">
        <center><h2>Sahne</h2></center>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <center><a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>1</a></center>
        <center><a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>2</a></center>
        <center><a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>3</a></center>
    </div>
    <div class="container2">
        <center><a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>4</a></center>
        <center><a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>5</a></center>
        <center><a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>6</a></center>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is how it looks currently. Not sure what exactly you want - http://jsfiddle.net/QSpZc/

Comment: Read this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: and what that has to do with anything @Sparky672

Comment: @Jawad:  It has **everything** to do with the OP not making himself very clear about what he's asking.

Comment: @Sparky672: Yup you are right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the containers to:

```
.container{}
.container2{
    clear:both;
}
```

And add `float:left;` to .docIcon

You can also drop the center elements, and add a `text-align:center;` style.

This will give you a layout with a row of A1, A2, and A3, and then a row beneath with A4 through A6.

[Example.](http://jsfiddle.net/MrNGb/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at : http://jsfiddle.net/DavidLaberge/cuDFu/

the key is a `float:left;` in your class `container`